# PrivilegeNotHeldException when privilege is given

Tags: windows, winapi, permissions

I'm creating a windows user by program an give the created user different privilege with [LsaAddAccountRights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ntsecapi/nf-ntsecapi-lsaaddaccountrights). Among other things the privilege "SeSecurityPrivilege" which is needed to receive ACL information.

This works on a lot of different Windows versions: 7, 8.1x, 10.x, Server 2019: My program runs by the user can access the ACL of the files (with C# *FileInfo.GetAccessControl()*). But this did not work on Server 2008R2 and 2012R2. (ATM I could not test Server 2016). All Servers are Domain Controller. Checking privileges with "whoami /priv" shows, that the SeSecurityPrivilege is set on Server 2019 (but disabled), but the other server none of the privileges are shown.

Writing a program queering the privileges with [LsaEnumerateAccountRights](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/win32/api/ntsecapi/nf-ntsecapi-lsaenumerateaccountrights) shows user has the privileges. Checking with [PrivilegeCheck](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/win32/api/securitybaseapi/nf-securitybaseapi-privilegecheck?redirectedfrom=MSDN) shows they are all disabled - on all Server (even 2019, where this is working).

Checking the group policy [Group Policy at DC](https://czerwsup.wordpress.com/2014/11/05/allow-log-on-locally-add-new-user-greyed-out-fix-via-domain-controller-policy-settings/) shows, that the Policy is assigned to the user.

Where is my problem? Why did this not work on the old Server version, but on the new one?

Comment: If the user has the privilege but it's not in the `whoami /priv` list (either enabled or disabled), then a policy is filtering it out when the user is logged on. Try elevating the user via "run as administrator". However, it's unexpected to require elevation if the privilege has been explicitly assigned to the user instead of indirectly obtained from the administrators group.

Answer (score 1):

Even when a particular account holds a given privilege most of the time most processes will run with the privilege disabled. Use AdjustTokenPrivileges to enable the privilege on a per-process basis (ideally you only enable the privilege for the time it is actually needed and re-disable it afterward). Note that you use LookupPrivilegeValue to get the LUID that identifies a privilege to AdjustTokenPrivileges.

Comment: I've tried [AdjustTokenPrivileges](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/win32/api/securitybaseapi/nf-securitybaseapi-adjusttokenprivileges?redirectedfrom=MSDN). This works on Windows 10, Server 2019 - where it is not necessary. But it did not work on Server 2008R2 - no error, just *PrivilegeCheck* keeps "disabled" and no ACL retrieve possible.